# differentiate the parameter with function

Tags: derivatives

It seems very basic but I can't understand...

Consider $f(x)=2x$. I want to differentiate $L=(x-f(x))b + 3(f(x))$ regarding $f(x)$.

When I looked at the solution, it says $\partial L/\partial f = -b+3$.

But I am confused because I can't get why $x$ is simply considered a constant and ignored. Shouldn't it be 
$$
(dx/df - 1)b+3 = (1/2-1)b+3=-b/2+3?
$$ 
Please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: I think $x=f(x)/2$ might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

$\partial L/\partial f $ means that it is partial derivative and therefore, treating any other variable as a constant. Therefore, in this case, $x$ will be treated as a constant and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0.$

Your answer will be right if the question was asking $$\frac{d L}{d f} $$